# Python: Can I access a class instance from class foo that was created in class bar?

Tags: python, class, instance

I have a class as follows:

```
class Hand():
    def __init__(self, hand_a, play_deck, split_count, name): # hand_a for hand actual
        self.hand_a = hand_a  # the actual hand when instance created
        self.play_deck = play_deck  #  need to move this to deck class
        self.split_count = split_count
        self.name = name
```

In another class I create an instance of Hand:

```
class DECK():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def deal(self, play_deck):
        dhand = {}
        phand = {}
        for i in range (2):
            play_deck, phand[i] = pick_item(play_deck)
            play_deck, dhand[i] = pick_item(play_deck)

        # creat instance of Hand for player's starting hand
        self.start_hand = Hand(phand, play_deck, 0, "Player 1")
```

In a third class I'm trying to access my first instance of Hand called 'start_hand':

```
class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def play_game(self):
        self.deck = DECK()
        self.deck.deal(play_deck)
        print "dhand = %r" % start_hand.hand_a
```

But I get the following error:

```
   print "dhand = %r" % start_hand.hand_a
NameError: global name 'start_hand' is not defined
```

I've also tried:

```
print "dhand = %r" % self.start_hand.hand_a
```

but I get the following error:

```
    print "dhand = %r" % self.start_hand.hand_a
AttributeError: Game instance has no attribute 'start_hand'
```

Do I have to create the class instance in some other way, or do I have to access it differently or both?  Or am I just so way off that I should start over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `start_hand` is a member of `deck` object.

```
print "dhand = %r" % self.deck.start_hand.hand_a
```

Comment: so is it fair to say that generally, instance 'a' created in instance 'b' becomes a member of instance 'b'?

Comment: @dwstein -- yep.  That sounds about right.  The important thing to realize is the the argument `self` *is the instance that the method is bound to*.

Comment: @mgilson is that true for most languages or is that Python specific?

Comment: @dwstein -- I don't really know.  Python is the only OOP language that I know well :X.  My impression is that python is a little strange with explicitly requiring that `self` is passed as the first argument to the method though.  I think that methods in C++ implicitly receive the "this" pointer which is similar to python's "self" (except that it is passed implicitly).  Also note that `self` is just a convention.  you're free to call it anything that is a valid identifier in python.  I wouldn't advise it though, `self` is pretty ubiquitous.

Comment: Another peculiarity of Python is that it's a dynamic language. Languages like Java and C++ require an explicit declaration of each class member/method before running a program, while Python programs construct their objects in runtime. You can create a `deck = DECK()` object and add one more member to it `deck.id = 3`. Another `DECK` instance won't have it unless you explicitly add it there too.

Comment: @MaximSkurydin -- That's correct.  But, I don't know how these things work with other interpretted languages (`perl`, or `ruby/rails`, ...).  I definitely wouldn't put python in a minority (or say that it is peculiar) simply because it's a dynamic language ... I'd expect that there are a lot more like it in that regard.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can access that attribute.  You want

```
self.deck.start_hand.hand_a
# ^ deck object you just created
#         ^Hand object created by the deck constructor/initiator (DECK.__init__)
#                    ^ starting hand attribute of hand object.
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try this?

```
def deal(self, play_deck):
  ...
  return start_hand
```

Otherwise `start_hand` is a member of the `DECK` object, so you would have to:

```
self.deck.start_hand
```

to access it.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I have to create the class instance in some other way, or do I have to access it differently or both? Or am I just so way off that I should start over?

Your problem is one of OO design more than python-specific features.  Decide how you want `Game`, `DECK`, and `Hand` to relate to one another.  Often, the appropriate solution is to create a method in the enclosing class that will delegate to its members.

It's hard to make a specific suggestion, because it looks like this might be some debug code.  But perhaps you could replace

```
print "dhand = %r" % start_hand.hand_a
```

with

```
print str(self.deck)
```

as long as you add a `__str__` method to `Deck`:

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.start_hand)
```

In order to be useful, you may need one for the `Hand` class as well.

Unsolicited advice: the `hand_a` ("hand actual") member of `Hand` creates a pretty confusing metaphor.  Consider making it a property of the `DECK` or something else that might make more sense.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer!  This is a sort of de-bug code in that it's an intermediate step.  I just used 'print' to make sure I had access to the dict.  Now that I do, i'll be adding more functionality.  What do you mean by a method that would "delegate to its members?  Thanks.